# Django/python indexerror

Tags: python

Exception Type:     IndexError
Exception Value:    list index out of range

i Have a form which inherits a model from , on saving the form instance i am getting the above error. Can you please suggest the cause of this error?

Answer (score 5):

The list has `n` elements, and you're trying to index it at `n` or greater. Restrict the index to between `0` and `n-1` inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, there is a dictionary of elemnents , let me say:

```
lst = {1:"1",
       2:"2",
       3:"3",
       4:"4",
       5:"5",
       7:"7",
       8:"8",
       9:"9"}
```

is a list of 8 numerics from 1 to 9 except 6.... If you try to get the value of element wth key 6, which is done using

```
lst[6]
```

your code returns you that error, becaouse ther eexists no key-value pair in your dictionary with key **6**.

So your form returns a key that do not exist in your value dictionary. It is hard to say anything without seeing your code.